# X11 forward to windows x server for docker client in AWS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, x11-forwarding

I am using windows mobaxterm for xserver and ssh client. If I type xclock in my ssh server (ubuntu 16.04)in AWS, the clock appears and there is not problem. Now I install nvidia-docker in AWS. Here is the run script for starting the docker container:

```
nvidia-docker run -it \
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-v /tmp/.docker.xauth:/tmp/.docker.xauth \
-e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth \
-net=host \
\
gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu  /bin/bash
```

The error i have is:

```
root@ip-172-31-35-73:/notebooks# xclock
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

the following seems to work.
 ssh from local terminal in mobaxterm:

ssh -X -Y  -i "C:\your_key_path\xxx.pem" root@xx.xx.xx.xx

in aws, start your docker as

```
nvidia-docker run -it \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \ 
-v /root/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority \
-e XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority \
--net=host \
\
gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu  /bin/bash
```

The results is:[image]